# WPF Datagrid has what looks like border in the column header on either side of the border between colums

Tags: c#, wpf

Datagrid with extra borders between column headers

[image: 1]

So i got these extra border looking lines between the column headers. i have found  simular problem but the solution did not apply for me.

my databrid looks like this:

```
<DataGrid Loaded="TransactionGrid_Loaded"  x:Name="TransactionGrid" CanUserAddRows="False"  HeadersVisibility="Column" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PreviewKeyDown="Transactions_PreviewKeyDown">
    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Utført Dato" Binding="{Binding DoneDateTime, ConverterCulture=nb-NO, StringFormat=d}" />

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kunde nr" Binding="{Binding Customer1.ID}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kunde navn" Binding="{Binding Customer1.Name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Timeart" Binding="{Binding TimeType.ID}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vare" Binding="{Binding Item1.ID}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Antall" Binding="{Binding Amount}" />

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kommentar" Binding="{Binding Comment}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I do not use any extra styling for the datagrid.

Comment: looks like modified style for ColumnHeaderGripperStyle. do you have anything for ColumnHeaderGripperStyle in project?

Comment: @tommylogon1 - What operating system do you have? Is it pure WPF environment or some custom library?

Comment: The only thing im styling in relation to any datagrid in my project is the DataGridTextColumn that has textwrapping. 

I run a Windows 10 Pro. i also Use the Xceed.WPF.TOOLKIT, Xceed.WPF.AvalonDock, Xceed.WPF.AvalonDock.Themes.Aero, Xceed.WPF.AvalonDock.Themes.Metro and Xceed.WPF.AvalonDock.Themes.VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

So i managed to solve this problem. i had a style targeting borders. as im not using this anymore i simply removed the style for borders